# Por que Python não usa 100% do processador?

Tags: python, python-3.x, desempenho, cpu

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo Python onde em alguns trechos, demanda muita CPU para cálculos.

Entretanto, percebo que mesmo nestes pontos de "gargalo", a CPU nunca chega a mais de 50% de uso.

Naturalmente o programa fica mais lento, enquanto tem CPU "de sobra" que poderia deixa-lo mais rápido.

Por exemplo, o processo abaixo demora (no meu PC), **15 segundos**:

```
from math import *
import time
ini = time.time()

for x in range(10**8):
    a = cos(x)

print ("Tempo Total: ", time.time() - ini)
```

Mas durante o processamento, apenas alguns processadores lógicos são usados, sendo que apenas 1 processador sofre mais demanda, ainda assim não chega a 100%:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como fazer com que o Python use 100% da CPU em processos críticos?

Comment: Utilizando mais threads, talvez. Aí tem que rever seu código para que ele use outras threads onde puder. Edita a pergunta para explicar o que seu programa faz, onde ele demandaria mais memória e o que vc tá utilizando pra isso (numpy, operações matemáticas, iterações em vetores, matrizes)...

Comment: @vnbrs, coloquei um exemplo.

Comment: Já viu algo sobre multi_threading?

Comment: Nem sempre usar 100% indica que será mais rápido.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No seu caso oque está acontecendo é o seguinte, você está executando sua rotina em uma única thread em um sistema (CPU) que possui 4 núcleos lógicos.

Você vai precisar reescrever seu algorítimo  para ser *multi-thread*, ou então verificar se voce consegue rodar instancias diferentes em núcleos específicos. Não conheço outra forma.

Vamos lá..

Montei um exemplo com calculo de tabuada para mostrar a diferença de performance entre cada um dos cenários.

> Cenário 1 - Execução SEM Thread

```
import time
ini = time.time()

def tabuada( threadName, numero):
    count = 0
    while count < 300000000:
        count +=1
        #print(" %s x %s = %s\n" % (numero, count, count*numero))
tabuada("Thread-1",2)
tabuada("Thread-1",3)
tabuada("Thread-1",4)


print ("Tempo Total: ", time.time() - ini)
```

Nessa execução tive resultado:

**Tempo Total:  35.65071749687195**

> Cenário 2 - Execução COM Thread em execução paralela

```
import time
import _thread
ini = time.time()

def tabuada( threadName, numero):
    count = 0
    while count < 100000000:
        count +=1
        #print(" %s x %s = %s\n" % (numero, count, count*numero))
    print ("Tempo Total: ", time.time() - ini)    

def tabuada2( threadName, numero):
    count = 0
    while count < 100000000:
        count +=1
        #print(" %s x %s = %s\n" % (numero, count, count*numero))
    print ("Tempo Total: ", time.time() - ini)      


def tabuada3( threadName, numero):
    count = 0
    while count < 100000000:
        count +=1
        #print(" %s x %s = %s\n" % (numero, count, count*numero))
    print ("Tempo Total: ", time.time() - ini)          

try:
    _thread.start_new_thread( tabuada, ("Thread12",2,) )
    _thread.start_new_thread( tabuada2, ("Thread14",3,) )
    _thread.start_new_thread( tabuada2, ("Thread15",4,) )
except:
    print('Erro')
```

Nessa execução tive resultado:

**Tempo Total:  10.11058759689331**

**Tempo Total:  11.129863500595093**

**Tempo Total:  11.548049688339233**

*Obs. O tempo total nesse caso foi de 11.54s, visto que, esse foi o tempo que mais demorou uma thread. E o tempo total exibido em cada linha representa o quanto cada thread demorou em sua execução.*

Como podemos notar o tempo cai muito quando dividimos a tarefa, mas por que?
Porque quando criamos threads diferentes o SO interpreta como processos diferentes e vai alocando em locais e núcleos diferentes dentro da minha CPU.

Sendo assim conforme havia dito no inicio, caso queira utilizar mais sua CPU e otimizar tempo de processamento aconselho a utilizar **threads**

Segue dois links bem bacanas sobre o conteúdo:

[Programação multi-thread em python](http://recologia.com.br/2015/07/programacao-multi-thread-em-python/)

[Python Threads](http://alissonmachado.com.br/python-threads/)

Comment: Excelente resposta e abordagem. Agora percebo que no meu exemplo, eu deveria recriar meu código dividindo em vários `for` com `ranges` diferentes, uma para cada thread. Muito obrigado.